# How do Fuel gauge ICs compensate for battery aging?

Tags: batteries, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, charge, fuel-gauge

I came across this [Fuel gauge IC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq27200.pdf?ts=1650369810093&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ27200)  recently and although I understand how the SOC is determined, I do not understand how the age compensation constant(the one used to determine the actual SOC) is derived.  I would like to know how the number of charge and discharge cycles is calculated by these ICs and also how to compensate for the aging effect according to the number of cycles.

Comment: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua364b/slua364b.pdf